# How can I disable screen staying off while I wakes up the PC from sleep

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, wake-up

Usually, When I wakes up the PC from sleep, I need to press any key two times, once to wake up the PC and then once more to wake up the monitor. Over time, that's bothering me. I hope there is a solution so I can wake them both when I press any key.

Thanks for any help,
bmt3

Comment: Monitors typically do wake up in that scenario. TVs don't. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I use dell s2319h (Which is typical PC's LED monitor), on my laptop setup as a external only display (the lid of the laptop stays down). in the past it was doing good, I believe after an windows update it turned to be like this.

Comment: How is it connected? HDMI?

Comment: That's right, HDMI.